# Angular JS ng-repeat with different filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small question.

I have this json object that

```
var map = {
    key1 : {filter:'bytes',value: 100000000},
    key2 : {filter:'ratio',value: 1.25}
};
```

I would like to use it with `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="key in map"> {{key.value | key.filter}}</div>
```

How can I accomplish this behaviour to get predefined filters implemented while in `ng-repeat`?

Comment: basicly your syntax shows `key.value`, or if that is null/undefined `key.filter`. You will want to tell angular to use a filter. I believe the proper way to do so is `{{key.value | filter:key.filter}}`

Comment: do you want do `{{val.value | ratio }}` and `{{val.value | bytes}}` but select filter dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a filter that invokes your customer filter like this:

```
filter('invokerFilter', function($filter) {
    return function(value ,filterName) {
        return $filter(filterName)(value) ;
};
```

I created an example for you [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CFb2BHO2PhTx9ThBHpuF?p=preview)

Comment: I did not. But I did something similar with the approach above several times.

Comment: it doesnt have to be an array, it will display the key.value, filtered by key.filter. This should work. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: yep, and get error `Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: 1.25`, from [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray?p0=100000000): _This error occurs when filter is not used with an array_, some [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WNASoeIof0rgsis377F2?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right, you want get something like

```
<div ng-repeat="key in map"> {{100000000 | bytes }}</div>
<div ng-repeat="key in map"> {{1.25 | ratio }}</div>
```

But angular raise error when try parse expression, instead get filter name from variable. So you can add a filter, that would be apply to source filter by name, something like

```
.filter('applyFilter',function($filter){
    return function(source, filterName){
        return $filter(filterName)(source);
    }
})
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.map = {
      key1: {
        filter: 'bytes',
        value: 100000000
      },
      key2: {
        filter: 'ratio',
        value: 1.25
      }
    };
  }).filter('bytes',function(){
    return function(a){
      return a + ' bytes';
    }
  }).filter('ratio',function(){
    return function(a){
      return 'ratio: ' + a;
    }
  }).filter('applyFilter',function($filter){
    return function(source, filterName){
      return $filter(filterName)(source);
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
      <div ng-repeat="key in map"> {{key.value | applyFilter: key.filter }}</div>
      
    </div>
```